# Consultar duas tabelas sem chave estrangeira e relacionamento

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas `tb_pedido` e `tb_pagamento`, coloquei um exemplo abaixo com alguns dados fictícios. Preciso de um relatório que apareça os dados da `tb_pedido` e da `tb_pagamento`, todos em uma única tabela como no exemplo 3. Pensei em fazer um left join mas nao consegui, preciso só acrescentar a coluna `data_pagamento` e `valor_pagamento` para finalizar o relatório.

```
TB_PEDIDO
COD_EMPRESA |COD_FORNECEDOR|DATA_EMISSAO|VALOR_PEDIDO|
1           |1             |01/11/2018  |1000        |
2           |2             |02/11/2018  |2000        |

TB_PAGAMENTO
COD_EMPRESA |COD_FORNECEDOR|DATA_ENTRADA|DATA_PAGAMENTO|VALOR_PAGAMENTO|
1           |1             |26/11/2018  |27/11/2018    |1000           |
2           |2             |26/11/2018  |28/11/2018    |2000           |


----------------------TB_PEDIDO----------------------|--------TB_PAGAMENTO----------|
COD_EMPRESA |COD_FORNECEDOR|DATA_EMISSAO|VALOR_PEDIDO|DATA_PAGAMENTO|VALOR_PAGAMENTO|
1           |1             |01/11/2018  |1000        |27/11/2018    |1000           |
2           |2             |02/11/2018  |2000        |28/11/2018    |2000           |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro criei as duas tabelas e inseri os dados conforme postado na pergunta (*Lembre-se de postar nas próximas perguntas, facilita bastante pra quem for lhe ajudar*):

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_pedido` (
    `COD_EMPRESA` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `COD_FORNECEDOR` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `DATA_EMISSAO` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `VALOR_PEDIDO` decimal(15,3)
) ENGINE=InnoDb;

INSERT INTO `tb_pedido` VALUES
    (1, 1, '2018-11-01', 1000),
    (2, 2, '2018-11-02', 2000);

CREATE TABLE `tb_pagamento`(
    `COD_EMPRESA` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `COD_FORNECEDOR` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `DATA_ENTRADA` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `DATA_PAGAMENTO` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `VALOR_PAGAMENTO` decimal(15,3)
) ENGINE=InnoDb;

INSERT INTO `tb_pagamento` VALUES
    (1, 1, '2018-11-26', '2018-11-27', 1000),
    (2, 2, '2018-11-26', '2018-11-28', 2000);
```

> Preciso de um relatório que apareça os dados da tb_pedido e da tb_pagamento, todos em uma única tabela como no exemplo 3

**Solução**:

```
SELECT
    tped.`COD_EMPRESA`, tped.`COD_FORNECEDOR`, tped.`DATA_EMISSAO`, tped.`VALOR_PEDIDO`, tpag.`DATA_PAGAMENTO`, tpag.`VALOR_PAGAMENTO`
FROM `tb_pedido` AS `tped`
JOIN `tb_pagamento` AS `tpag`
    ON(tped.`COD_EMPRESA` = tpag.`COD_EMPRESA` AND tped.`COD_FORNECEDOR` = tpag.`COD_FORNECEDOR`);
```

**Saída** (*Como no exemplo 3*):

```
+-------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| COD_EMPRESA | COD_FORNECEDOR | DATA_EMISSAO        | VALOR_PEDIDO | DATA_PAGAMENTO      | VALOR_PAGAMENTO |
+-------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|           1 |              1 | 2018-11-01 00:00:00 |     1000.000 | 2018-11-27 00:00:00 |        1000.000 |
|           2 |              2 | 2018-11-02 00:00:00 |     2000.000 | 2018-11-28 00:00:00 |        2000.000 |
+-------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

*Esta é uma consulta simples e que deve ser implementada conforme sua aplicação.*

**Lembrando**: As chaves estrangeiras asseguram a integridade dos dados armazenados (Um dos pilares do MySQL). Utilizando desta forma, pode-se apagar dados de uma tabela que estariam associados a outra tabela... Ainda não sendo uma boa prática, não é o objetivo da pergunta "corrigir" seu banco de dados, mas sim reproduzir uma consulta associando as tabelas independente da existência de chaves estrangeiras.

> Assista essa playlist e entenda tudo: [Curso em Vídeo - Bancos de dados MySQL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=paZNDJAPT4E&list=PLHz_AreHm4dkBs-795Dsgvau_ekxg8g1r&index=17)

Answer (score 0):

você pode utilizar os 2 primeiros campos como estrangeira:

```
SELECT 
    a.COD_EMPRESA, a.COD_FORNECEDOR, a.DATA_EMISSAO,a.VALOR_PEDIDO,b.DATA_ENTRADA,b.DATA_PAGAMENTO, b.VALOR_PAGAMENTO
from TB_PEDIDO a, TB_PAGAMENTO b
where 
    a.COD_EMPRESA=b.COD_EMPRESA AND a.COD_FORNECEDOR=b.COD_FORNECEDOR
```

Comment: Seriam os 3 primeiros campos, não? Pois se a data de emissão é diferente o pedido não é o mesmo.

Comment: Não, pois vc pode emitir o pedido em um dia e o cliente pagar outro dia...